# versioning parameter not working properly

Tags: foursquare

when using url : https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?v=20120321 i get photo url "photo": "https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix_thumbs/-NH21T0X1FCTGSY1W.png", which is correct and image is shown when browsed in browser

but when i use https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?v=20131114 i get below response for photo:
"photo":  {
        "prefix": "https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/",
        "suffix": "/-NH21T0X1FCTGSY1W.png"
      },

which when attached becomes url https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/-NH21T0X1FCTGSY1W.png
and says "Internal Error" when browsed in browser.

The above check was performed via https://apigee.com/console/foursquare

Comment: Interesting. It seems that Foursquare is messing up with the pictures URLs.

Comment: Waiting answer from foursquare development/support team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a full photo URL, as we detail in our docs: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo

You need to insert a size between `prefix` and `suffix`. For example, https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/300x300/-NH21T0X1FCTGSY1W.png is a working image.

Comment: where is this stated in foursquare api documentation that size should be inserted, any link ? @octopi